# Saving and restoring an ArrayDeque onSaveInstanceState

Tags: java, android, android-savedstate

I am working on an video app thats uses an ArrayDeque to store our history of videos viewed, using push, pop. It works well but I'm looking for a clean way of saving and restoring the ArrayDeque

```
private Deque<ProgramModel> mVideoHistory = new ArrayDeque<>();
```

I save the list by saving it as an arraylist.

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(final Bundle outState) {
    // save history
    ArrayList<ProgramModel> history = new ArrayList<>();
    for (ProgramModel program : mVideoHistory) {
        history.add(program);
    }
    outState.putParcelableArrayList("videoHistory", history);
}
```

Then I restore it

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    // restore history
    ArrayList<ProgramModel> history =
            savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("videoHistory");
    mVideoHistory = new ArrayDeque<>(history);
}
```

Can it be done in a more efficient/cleaner way than this?

Ive tried `outState.putSerializable("videoHistory", mVideoHistory.toArray());` but restoring caused me problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
outState.putSerializable("videoHistory", (ArrayDeque<ProgramModel>) mVideoHistory);
```

cast again when restoring.

hope it helps

Comment: thanks for the fast reply, seems my ProgramModel wont play nice this way, it gives me `Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object `

Comment: ProgramModel implements Serializable? If it does, check that all of the types attributes members of ProgramModel implement Serializable.